# How do I sub-login to ixl.com?

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, python-requests, python-webbrowser

In ixl.com, I managed to sign in using Python. But there is a sub-login. How do I do that?
Here is my code so far:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("https://ixl.com")

loginData = {
    "qlusername": "admin",
    "qlpassword": "12345",
}

with requests.session() as s:
    res = s.post("https://eu.ixl.com/signin/ajax/page", data=loginData
    print(res.text)
```

Comment: What is a sub-login?

Comment: It's like another login after you login. It's a little hard to explain